# Connecting phonegap with Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, post, cordova, dialog

Please, any help/solutions for this:  connecting and merging Facebook with our phonegap application (version 3.0.9) so we may post on Facebook - from the phonegap applicaton's behalf using the post dialog.

Basically, when an action is done on the application, it would post to Facebook (such as when someone is listening to a song on Spotify and it says on FB, or when someone likes something on Instagram and it posts on FB, etc).

We are using phonegap version 3.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook plugin would be your best, and easiest, bet. Take a look at the documentation found [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

Comment: Thanks, that is the same documentation I have been following...just has me stumped though.

Comment: Post some code and what you have tried and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: while using the facebook plugin, I receive the error: CDV variable does not exist. Check that you have included cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js correctly, and then the error: FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file

and I AM including the files described

<!-- cordova facebook plugin -->
  <script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
     <!-- facebook js sdk -->
  <script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>

that is the oddest part

that is when I try to use the FB plugin

Comment: when I DON'T use the FB plugin but instead I go through the inAppBrowser, I DO get logged into FB with our application, BUT I can't return to the application itself, everything gets stuck in the response from our server

that is the question here

Comment: I can connect to Facebook, but I cannot return to the application connected to Facebook to execute what I need to do, which is execute post dialog.